# How to have interior form respond to key down events?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a MainView form that just contains a panel. I use a separate class (Presenter) to govern what form will be shown in that panel depending on different events. When one of these sub-forms are shown I want to be able to press a key down and have that sub-form respond; however, the keydown event does not hit in the sub-form, only the main form.

I want to know how to get the sub-form to respond to key events ***without*** going from MainView -> Presenter -> SubView.

Comment: Can you not just add an event listener on the sub-form?

Comment: You want the `KeyPreview` property

Comment: @Jonesopolis I tried setting the KeyPreview property to true, and it still wont hit the breakpoint at the beginning of the Key_Down event.

Comment: @Pseudonym I'm trying to avoid that because I want the program flow to have to go through the Presenter class if it needs to talk from view to view.

Comment: Ahh okay, I understand now

Comment: Override [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) in main `Form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Presenter class is aware of the form it is putting into the panel, it will also need to get from that form or from associated data what control in the form is meant to have default focus.  Presumably, your Presenter class has a method that shows a given form on that panel, so you do something like:

```
Presenter.ShowForm(MainViewPanel, Form1);
```

You would then need to do something like:

```
Form1.Controls.OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex).First().Focus();
```

Comment: Do not set the focus on the form.  Set the focus on a control in the form.

Answer (score 0):

What has the focus? If you don't have a control in the child form with the focus, it will never see the keyboard events.

---

Also, try setting KeyPreview to true on the child form.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am programatically adding the sub-form to MainView's panel.Controls collection. I added the line subForm.Focus(); but it still didn't work. Also the KeyPreview being set to true doesn't seem to be working either. It doesn't trigger the breakpoint.

Comment: It's been awhile since I did WinForms programming, but I don't think the form itself can have the focus. I think it has to be a control.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured out what my issue was. It was a combination of a few of the posts, but I wanted to put everything down that I had to do in one place.

I have a method that looks like this:

```
private void DisplayView(Form view)
{
    if (view == null || view == _mainView) return;

    view.TopLevel = false;
    _mainView.GameArea.Controls.Clear();
    _mainView.GameArea.Controls.Add(view);
    view.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    view.BringToFront();
    view.Show();
    _mainView.GameArea.Controls[0].Focus();
}
```

This was the line that fixed it:

```
_mainView.GameArea.Controls[0].Focus();
```

Rather than going through the "view" variable and setting focus, I was able to set focus to the view this way.

I also had to remove the other views from the panel's collection as well:

```
_mainView.GameArea.Controls.Clear();
```